# Unable to process multipart/report data in Spring 5.0.1. It is only detecting multipart/form-data in the request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, multipartform-data

I am using Spring 5.0.1 and servlet 3.1.0

When user sends multipart/form-data in the request, spring is able to parse the request and make the parts out of it.
request.getParts() will have those provided multiparts.

But when user sends multipart/report (content-type), spring does not parse this request properly.
It does not give any exception but it does not store anything in the request parts.
request.getParts() will return empty array.

Is there any configuration that has to be done so that spring parses any kind of multipart data.

Posting my code and request payload below:

REST API does not have any restriction on the content type. It takes only request and response as parameters as shown below:

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/rest/external/integration/{serviceName}", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
public void executeAssemblyExternal (HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String serviceName)  throws Exception    
{        
      Parts[] requestParts = request.getParts();   
}
```

Content-type header which is being sent with the request is :
Content-Type    multipart/report; Report-Type=disposition-notification;    boundary="----=_Part_82_645653877.1526452736757"

Multipart data which is being sent to the REST API is as below:

------=_Part_82_645653877.1526452736757
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

MDN for -
  Message ID: <1088014046.24.1526452734879@MCBKUM03.eur.ad.sag>
  From: SenderAS2
  To: ReceiverAS2
  Received on: 2018-05-16 at 12:08:56 (IST)
  Status: processed
  Comment: This is not a guarantee that the message has been completely processed or understood by the receiving translator

------=_Part_82_645653877.1526452736757
Content-Type: message/disposition-notification
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Reporting-UA: webMethods Integration Server
Original-Recipient: rfc822; ReceiverAS2
Final-Recipient: rfc822; ReceiverAS2
Original-Message-ID: <1088014046.24.1526452734879@MCBKUM03.eur.ad.sag>
Received-content-MIC: SezQZhP0aSchqB1zCO0Dq4J0u3U=, sha1
Disposition: automatic-action/MDN-sent-automatically; processed

------=_Part_82_645653877.1526452736757--

Comment: post your code so we can see

Comment: No configuration will help. The servlet api default upload handling (as well as `commons-fileupload` will only parse the `multipart/form-data` based requests.

Comment: Thanks for responses. Posted my code in the question. @M. Denium: Is there any way to provide other upload handlers of the servlet so that it handles all the multipart types.?

Answer (score 0):

As Deinum mentioned in a comment, servlet can not handle multipart requests other than multipart/form-data. 
So Written a custom dispatcherServlet where requests having header Content-Type as multipart with subtype other than form-data will be bypassed from getting processed through MultipartResolver.

By doing this request.getInputStream() will have whole multipart data as sent by the user. Necessary actions can be performed on this inputstream at the server side.

Comment: You don't need a custom `DispatcherServlet` you can parse the request in an `@Controller` annotated method. If you don't need file uploads at al you can just disable file uploading.